# select using time stamp

Tags: sql, t-sql

When I'm querying that:

```
select * from EventLog as q
where EventTypeId = 3 and q.SomeUserId is not null
order by q.UserId, q.TimeStamp
```

example result is:

```
 ID USERID SomeUserId EventTypeId  
 36723  1   2333    3   13001009809 NULL    115 2015-01-23 14:56:42.860
 36735  1   2334    3   13001009809 NULL    12  2015-01-23 15:48:14.363
 36747  1   2335    3   13001009809 NULL    33  2015-01-23 21:22:48.007
 36769  1   2338    3   13001009809 NULL    22  2015-01-24 11:55:29.100
 36853  1   2347    3   13001009999 NULL    61  2015-07-06 17:24:33.817
 36863  1   2351    3   13001034120 NULL    25  2015-12-23 11:42:48.463
 36873  1   2352    3   13001034120 NULL    25  2015-12-23 11:46:25.030
 36883  1   2353    3   13001034120 NULL    10  2015-12-23 11:49:09.553
 964    10  826 3   01005000095 NULL    NULL    2013-01-30 15:52:17.653
 973    10  829 3   01009005715 NULL    NULL    2013-01-30 16:20:46.293
 637    12  752 3   35001091797 NULL    NULL    2013-01-15 16:50:54.567
 738    12  767 3   35001091159 NULL    NULL    2013-01-18 10:53:04.143
 1316   12  870 3   35001119598 NULL    NULL    2013-02-07 11:36:28.503
 1377   12  888 3   59002002288 NULL    NULL    2013-02-07 13:24:57.777
 1389   12  892 3   35001104167 NULL    NULL    2013-02-07 14:01:40.920
 1408   12  897 3   20001009805 NULL    NULL    2013-02-07 15:05:08.577
```

and last one is timestamp (another doesn't matter)

How can I select that result be this:

for example monthly registered SomeUserId is:

> January 20 // 0 + 20 = 20
>
> February 50 // 20 + 40 = 70
>
> March 35 // 70 + 35 = 105. now it's 100+. so after that query must
>   return everything from scratch
>
> April 10 // 0 + 10 = 10 etc

and that for each SomeUserId (which here are 1, 10, 12..)

It's based on 100 registered user (it doesn't matter there will 3 or 12 months).

Comment: Please add column name in Header of row table data to help us.... also would this iteration be reset after each quarter(3 month) or it is based on April to Mar financial system.... Please confirm?

Comment: @jitendrajoshi I've edited

Comment: @George , can you describe what do you need finally more detail? After "How can I select that result be this:..."

Comment: @PavelSamoylenko main idea is that I want to select when concrete registrar(UserId) has registered more than 100 user. after that month (last day and last minute of month) will start count from scratch (as it's on blockquote)

Comment: [`timestamp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx) is a type in SQL that has nothing to do with time (it was renamed to `rowversion` in later versions of SQL) Please do not use the term `timestamp` to refer to a "time stamp"

Comment: Why do you tag this with Entity Framework and Linq?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table(yyyymm varchar(30), value int)
insert into @t values ('2015-01', 20)
insert into @t values ('2015-02', 50)
insert into @t values ('2015-03', 35)
insert into @t values ('2015-04', 10)
insert into @t values ('2015-02', 13)
insert into @t values ('2015-04', 11)
insert into @t values ('2015-04', 111)
insert into @t values ('2015-05', 12)

declare @result table(yyyymm varchar(30), value int)

insert into @result
select yyyymm, sum(value)
from @t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm

declare @yyyymm varchar(30)
declare @value int, @valueIncrement int
set @valueIncrement=0

--select * from @result

declare #Cr CURSOR local for
    select yyyymm, value
    from @result
open #Cr
FETCH NEXT FROM #Cr INTO @yyyymm, @value
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF(@@FETCH_STATUS <> -2)
    BEGIN
        set @valueIncrement=@valueIncrement+@value

        if (not @value=@valueIncrement) begin
            update @result
            set value=@valueIncrement
            where yyyymm=@yyyymm
        end;

        if (@valueIncrement>=100) set @valueIncrement=0
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM #Cr INTO @yyyymm, @value
END
close #Cr
deallocate #Cr  

--select * from @t order by yyyymm
select * from @result
```

Comment: thanks Pavel for replies. in your code after 2015-04 result of needed is 115. instead it must be 10 (after first 3 months it's greater than 100 so value of needed must be summed from 0. 0 + 10 = 10 not 115)

Comment: it works on that 3 month but what if there will 103 registered user on first month?

Comment: @George bug fixed. About a previous question. Can you show this situation in code?

Comment: question is that in your code you have quarters but I don't need them. Take a look at that code http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7223e/2/0 in 4th month there is 132 registration (It's > 100) so 5th month should be 12, 6th 24, 7th 36 and when it will > 100 it should start count from scratch

Comment: @George Sorry for delay. Check please edited variant. I wrong understood task. I couldn't make query without a loop. But it is not a scary loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE expression.

```
select *,
CASE    
WHEN  salary <= 2000 THEN set SomeUserId = 10
END AS salary_level
FROM employees
```

Comment: and how can i use that on date?